How to get VS Code / Godot to load the right libsteam_api file?
I'm currently watching a tutorial series right now to get Steamworks initialized with Godot using the Facepunch implementation, but every time I try to connect with the following C# script I get an error:
using Godot;
using System;
using Steamworks;

public partial class SteamManager : Node2D
{
    public static SteamManager Manager { get; set; }
    private static uint gameAppId { get; set; } = 480;
    public string PlayerName { get; set; }
    public SteamId PlayerSteamId { get; set; }
    private bool connectedToSteam { get; set; }

    public SteamManager()
    {
        if (Manager == null)
        {
            Manager = this;

            try
            {
                SteamClient.Init(gameAppId, true);

                if (!SteamClient.IsValid)
                {
                    GD.Print("Something went wrong steam client not working");
                    throw new Exception();
                }

                PlayerName = SteamClient.Name;
                PlayerSteamId = SteamClient.SteamId;
                connectedToSteam = true;
                GD.Print("Steam is connected. Player name is " + PlayerName);
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                connectedToSteam = false;
                GD.Print("Error connecting to steam. " + e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}

Error triggered by catch:
> Error Connecting To Steam: Unable to load shared library 'libsteam_api' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES environment variable: dlopen(liblibsteam_api, 0x0001): tried: '/Applications/Godot_mono 4.2.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/liblibsteam_api' (no such file), '/Applications/Godot_mono 4.2.app/Contents/MacOS/liblibsteam_api' (no such file), 'liblibsteam_api' (no such file), '/usr/lib/liblibsteam_api' (no such file), '/Users/---/Desktop/Games/rts2/liblibsteam_api' (no such file)

I've tried to move the libsteam file into the root folder so that the script maybe could find it, but the problem is that it insists on looking for liblibsteam_api. I don't know how to switch it so that it looks for libsteam_api, so any help would be appreciated.
